# How to use Spring Security's JDBC authentication without using "authorities"?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-security

I have problem with authorities.

> Reason: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select
>   username,authority from authorities where username = ?]; nested
>   exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
>   "authorities" does not exist Position: 32

I don't want to implement authorities, but don't know how to disable it in JavaConfig in Spring.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password,'true' as enabled from users where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't deactivate the authorities mechanism with JavaConfig in Spring Security but you can override the query used to fetch the authorities data to achieve the same effect.

When using Spring Security's JDBC authentication, it makes certain assumptions about the database scheme to retrieve authentication data. You already override the query used to fetch the user data in your example with the the call to `usersByUsernameQuery()`.

I managed to effectively disable the whole authorities check by also overriding the query to fetch authorities data like this (as described in "Spring in Action" by Craig Walls):

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)
        throws Exception {

    authenticationManagerBuilder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "SELECT username, 'ROLE_USER' FROM users WHERE username=?");
}
```